# Accessing field SenderNetworkId on ChatterMessage object

Tags: chatter, permissions, fields

As stated [here](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_api_objects_changed.htm) and [here](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_chattermessage.htm), Salesforce added the SenderNetworkId field on the ChatterMessage object on its Spring 15 release (API 32.0).

However, when querying this field, like this

```
select Id, SenderNetworkId from ChatterMessage
```

I get the following error:

```
System.QueryException: No such column 'SenderNetworkId' on entity 'ChatterMessage'
```

This happens if I run the query on the Developer Console, for example. I'm on a Spring 15 org.

There are no field security settings for the ChatterMessage object.

My user has all the chatter related settings on its profile activated.

Any ideas about what might be going on?

Thanks,

Antonio

Comment: "This field is available only if Salesforce Communities is enabled in your organization." I assume this is the case for your org since you are interested in this field.

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Also, under the particular community settings, I have checked "Enable Private Messages".